# How can I get exact text using contains and first?

Tags: jquery

Im trying to get exact text "us" in a Div class .tld-assigned, but right now it gets all text in Div class .tld-assigned that have "us" and "usa", and not only "us".
How can I get exact text using contains and first?

```js
jQuery(".tld-assigned:contains(us)").first()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$('.tld-assigned').filter(function(){

return $(this).text()=="us"

}).first().css("color","red")
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="tld-assigned">us</span>
<span class="tld-assigned">usa</span>
<span class="tld-assigned">ausa</span>
<span class="tld-assigned">us</span>
```

1. use `.filter()`
2. With `.first()`